# How define a interface or class with a generic type who's generic type holds a generic type

Tags: c#, oop, generics, types, interface

I want to define a house having multiple (special and normal)rooms each having a collection of (special and normal)things.

I started using generics for my ThingCollection(and derived classes), but when I wanted to define my Room types I start having errors with my generic type defintions.

Does anyone know a proper way of defining my interfaces/classes so I won't get this error message?

Code:

```
namespace City.Street.House
{
    // Thing(s)
    public interface IThing{ }
    public interface ISpecialThing : IThing { }

    // Collection(s)
    public interface ThingCollection<TThing> where TThing : IThing { }
    public interface SpecialThingCollection<TThing> : ThingCollection<TThing> where TThing : ISpecialThing { }

    // Room(s)  // Error On TThing in both rows below:
    public interface Room<TThingCollection> where TThingCollection : ThingCollection<TThing> { } 
    public interface SpecialRoom<TThingCollection> : Room<TThingCollection> where TThingCollection : SpecialThingCollection<TThing> { }

    // House(s)
    public interface House { }
}
```

Error message:

> **CS0246:** The type or namespace name 'TThing' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Please avoid adding screenshots of code or error messages - they usually just make the question harder to read. Instead, include them as text. I've removed the images from your post since you've already provided proper code. For more information, read the accepted answer of ["Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `TThing` as a type parameter in the generic constraint unless it's also defined in the method's signature as well - so `Room<TThingCollection>` should become `Room<TThingCollection, TThing>` - 
but for this to work you need to add more constraints:

```
public interface Room<TThingCollection<TThing>> 
    where TThingCollection : ThingCollection<TThing> 
    where TThing : IThing
{ }

public interface SpecialRoom<TThingCollection<TThing>> : Room<TThingCollection> 
    where TThingCollection : SpecialThingCollection<TThing> 
    where TThing : ISpecialThing
{ }
```

Or you can use the interfaces you've declared as the generic constraints (change `TThing` to `IThing` and `ISpecialThing`:

```
 // Room(s)
public interface Room<TThingCollection> where TThingCollection : ThingCollection<IThing> { }
public interface SpecialRoom<TThingCollection> : Room<TThingCollection> where TThingCollection : SpecialThingCollection<ISpecialThing> { }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Zohar Your well given answer made me refactor the code a little.

I used this part of your code:

```
// Room(s)
public interface Room<TThingCollection> where TThingCollection : ThingCollection<IThing> { }
public interface SpecialRoom<TThingCollection> : Room<TThingCollection> where TThingCollection : SpecialThingCollection<ISpecialThing> { }
```

Also I had to change the collections interfaces to this:

```
// Collection(s)
public interface ThingCollection<TThing> where TThing : IThing { }
public interface SpecialThingCollection<TSpecialThing> : ThingCollection<IThing> where  TSpecialThing : ISpecialThing{ }
```

Without these collection changes it wouldn't work.

Thanks for the help, much appreciated!